# How to Execute the function after Ajax call is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, liferay

I have two functions,in 1st function having  ajax call,so i want the 2nd function to be execute after ajax call (here i am reloading the page)complete,can you please help me?
Here the below code

```
<div id="exapnd_or_collapse_div" class="exapnd_or_collapse_div" onclick="changeLayout();">
<script>
function changeLayout () {
    alert('change layout');

    try {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'<%=resourceURL.toString()%>',
            dataType: "text",
            data:{
                <portlet:namespace  />cmd:'changeLayout'
            },
            error: function(){
             alert("AJAXError");
            },
            type: "post",

            success: function(data) {

                if("success" == data) {

                    location.reload();
                }
            }
        }).done(function(){
            exapndCollapse(); 
          });


    } catch(e) {
        alert('waiting: ' + e);
    }
};

function expandCollapse() {


            jQuery("div.Search_Styled-dropDown").css("display", "none");
            jQuery("span.menu-text").css("display", "none");

            jQuery("ul.Common_ul").css("display", "none");
            jQuery("img.module_images").css("width", "25px");
            jQuery("img.module_images").css("margin-top", "20px");
        jQuery("img.module_images").css("height", "21px");
            jQuery("#search_box").css("display", "none");   
        jQuery("#Escaped_toggle").css("margin-right", "94%");   
        }
</script>
```

Comment: location.reload(); in success reload page without call your function

Comment: after reloading only i want to call expandCollapse();

Comment: if you reload page then you are not able to get ajax done request . page reload will not mange ajax complete  event .

Comment: Check your spelling: `exapndCollapse()` <> `expandCollapse()`. Is that your problem? What is and what isn't working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you know Ajax is to make Asynchronous request. It means client no need to wait till you get the response from server. ***So during this Ajax object goes different states*** (**i.e. from 0 to 4**). Those are:

- 0: request not initialized
- 1: server connection established
- 2:    request received
- 3:    processing request
- 4: request finished and response is ready

**So as per your requirement there is two solution:**

- either you make synchronous request (but it is not recommended)
- you need to call your 2nd function when readystate value is 4

**Refer below code, it will help you:**

```
function changeLayout() {
    try{
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'<%=resourceURL.toString()%>',
            dataType: "text",
            data:{
                <portlet:namespace  />cmd:'changeLayout'
            },
            type: "post",

            beforeSend: function(){
                //before send this method will be called
            },
            success: function(data) {
                //when response recieved then this method will be called.
            }
            complete: function(){
                //after completed request then this method will be called.
            },
            error: function(){
                //when error occurs then this method will be called.
            }
        });
    }catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Try to use portlet preferences to save the state of your object. As you are trying to reload the page so you will lose all the states of the object. So whatever you perform after it, is not going to reflect @PVBRaju

Answer (score 2):

Try this but i have created example change the code as per your requirement

```
function exapndCollapse(){

    //execute your script here
    //if u want reload the page means write your script here

}

function changeLayout () {
var myval = 'test';
    $.ajax({
          url:'script.php',
          type: "POST",
          data: {"myval":myval},
          success: function(data){
              //call the after ajax success 
              exapndCollapse(); //whatever the function call 
          },error: function() { 
              console.log("error");
          } // This is always fired
   });   
};
```